# Count a distinct value with a distinct condition on SQL

Tags: sql-server

I need some help regarding a count statement for a specific value linked to another distinct value. Lets try to explain this.

**Current Data (Output)**

```
    Policy Number|Member Number|Ben Type|Principal|Spouse|Child
    1234          ABCD              M      
    1234          ABCD              S
    1234          ABCD              C
    1234          ABCD              C

    1234          EFGH              M
    1234          EFGH              C
    1234          EFGH              C
```

**Required Output Report**

```
    Policy Number|Member Number|Ben Type|Principal|Spouse|Child
    1234          ABCD              M       1         1     2

    1234          EFGH              M       1         0     2
```

M Principle Member
S Spouse
C Child Dependant

The data contains more columns for example first name etc. I would however like the count of the Ben Type indicator to reflect only on the line whereby the Principle Members information is displayed (Ben Type = M).

The below code counts ALL the Ben Type Indicators without using the  Policy Number as the distinct value. There can be X2 Policy Numbers with X 1 Member Number. Thus the distinct value will be the Policy Number and the Member Number.

```
UPDATE 
  [XRef1] 
SET
  [Child] = 
(SELECT COUNT([Ben Type])
FROM
  [Xref1]
WHERE
  [Ben Type] = 'C')
```

Here is another example I tried, however I know it probably wont work as it wont return all columns and only the Policy Number and the count will be incorrect?
The below error was generated.
(Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS)

```
UPDATE 
  XRef1
SET     
  [Child] = 
(SELECT DISTINCT[Policy Number],COUNT([Ben Type])
FROM    
  XRef1
WHERE   
  [Ben Type] = 'C'
GROUP BY  
  [policy Number])
```

I don't know anything really about the Exists statement, however I read up on it and followed some queries and came to the below. it is incorrect and basically the sub-query is a duplicate of the main query. The same error was generated.

```
 UPDATE 
   XRef1
 SET        
   [Child] = 
 (SELECT DISTINCT[Policy Number],COUNT([Ben Type])
 FROM       
   XRef1
 WHERE  
   [Ben Type] = 'C'
 GROUP BY  
   [policy Number])
 WHERE EXISTS 
 (SELECT DISTINCT[Policy Number],COUNT([Ben Type])
 FROM       
   XRef1
 WHERE  
   [Ben Type] = 'C'
 GROUP BY  
   [policy Number])
```

Please tell me if I am at all on the right track or trying to make this a lot more complicated than it actually is.

Comment: you are sure you need an update?

Comment: How about a simple PIVOT, with Policy Number and Member Number as Rows, Ben Type as your Columns and a Count as your value. If you still want Ben Type to appear, always with a value of 'M', just CROSS JOIN this at the end. I can expand on this if you want.

Comment: Yes please can you expand on this, I think I follow but not 100% convinced that I do.

Comment: Posted the answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT PolicyNumber, MemberNumber, 'M' AS BenType,
    [M], [S], [C]
    FROM
    (SELECT PolicyNumber, MemberNumber, BenType 
        FROM #Data) AS SourceTable
    PIVOT
    (
    COUNT(BenType)
    FOR BenType IN ([M], [S], [C])
    ) AS PivotTable;
```

[Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) is some info on the PIVOT operator.

Comment: Wow if I knew it was going to be that easy, I would have posted the question hours ago. Thanks a million this is exactly what I wanted and the calculations are spot on. Will just do an Inner Join with the rest of the data.Thanks for the Info on the PIVOT, will def read up on it.